# How to delete lines between 2 line patterns using regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++, lines

So I have a file like:

```
    FLAGSHARE
    xxxxxx
    xxxxx, 1 2015

    words....

    FLAGSHARE
    xxxxxx
    xxxxx, 2 2015

    words....

    FLAGSHARE
    xxxxxx
    xxxxx, 3 2015

    words....
```

etc.etc.

How would I be able to delete the three lines FLAGSHARE, xxxxxx, 
xxxxx, * 2015 (essentially remove FLAGSHARE, 2015 and lines between FLAGSHARE and 2015) using Notepad++?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following to match:

```
FLAGSHARE[\s\S]*?2015
```

And replace with `''` (empty string)

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cD2rD8/9)

Comment: With this pattern if `FLAGSHARE` is followed by for example `2013`, it will remove all the lines until `2015` is found. https://regex101.com/r/rR1wP0/1

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you are right.. if OP has cases like that.. I will update the answer :)

Comment: I had the same use case. I wanted to delete some code from a file which is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
FLAGSHARE[\S\s]*?\d{4}
```

## [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vY2hJ6/2)

Which will also match any year

You could also use:

```
FLAGSHARE[\S\s]*?20\d{2}
```

For any year int he format: 20**

Or even:

```
FLAGSHARE[\S\s]*?\d\s*\d\n
```

Which will work in all situations

## [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vY2hJ6/3)